# PDF thumbnails in TeXShop (LaTeX)

Tags: latex, pdftex

How can i create PDF thumbnails in TeXShop using LaTeX and thumbpdf?

I have `\usepackage{thumbpdf}` in my preamble, ran LaTeX twice, ran

```
$ thumbpdf report.pdf
```

from a Terminal (I'm on a Mac), then ran LaTeX again, but the PDF has no thumbnails? Am I missing a step?

The thumbpdf command created png files but then deleted them again, and wrote a file called report.tpt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you're missing is that you might want to run /usr/bin/latex rather than thumbpdf.

Hope this helps.